# Conditonal typescript type property based on another property's value

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type out the [HTTP PATCH document structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) and could have sworn I'd seen conditional Typescript properties based on another prop value, but I can't be sure.  There may also be a way to do this via union types...

Here's the schema:

```
[
 { "op": "test", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": "foo" },
 { "op": "remove", "path": "/a/b/c" },
 { "op": "add", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": [ "foo", "bar" ] },
 { "op": "replace", "path": "/a/b/c", "value": 42 },
 { "op": "move", "from": "/a/b/c", "path": "/a/b/d" },
 { "op": "copy", "from": "/a/b/d", "path": "/a/b/e" }
]
```

Note, there's an `op` property whose values can be `"test" | "remove" | "add" | "replace" | "move" | "copy"`.  The `move` and `copy` operations have a `from` property and do not contain the `value` property that the others (except for `remove`) have.

Clearly, I can just make `from` and `value` optional and move on with my life, but I lose the validation aspect so I was wondering if it was possible (if not exactly easy) to define types that adhere to the schema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types), specifically discriminated unions.

```
type Schema =
  | { "op": "test", "path": string, "value": string }
  | { "op": "remove", "path": string }
  | { "op": "add", "path": string, "value": string[] } // value can be [string, string]
  | { "op": "replace", "path": string, "value": 42 }
  | { "op": "move", "from": string, "path": string }
  | { "op": "copy", "from": string, "path": string }


let o: Schema = { op: "move", from: "", path: "" }
let o2: Schema = { op: "remove", from: "", path: ""} // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=11&ssc=60&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLwCgpQD5QDeUARAPZgkBcpwEAzsCQDSlirALVSMBOAlgDsA5qxIA3VABsArhG58hwqAF8c+IqQrcSvFGXHyx7TguACRq9QWLlKNEqgAmTlmw5caikWMmz5XuZKANoAuqpQAPSRUH5yUHCoglAARtDB3qI8QSKh1pp2OnpgUqhwRu6mgRZZEtJy3AAsAExWuDZa9qTIBhUkAGa8ZMhmNcYeo0ptGrbaDnAUIG4DQyPVSuNV2TXTWFhSEMBQZDTwSGiYmhQOPYZug8MObiYIT1YHR2TNp4go6BhXMAOPS3CoPZBPVgvJ4qKIxCC8XhAA)

Comment: This is the correct answer; this kind of type is called a "discriminated union" or "tagged union" because the `op` property can be used to test (and narrow) which branch of the union the object has.

Comment: Interesting.  Does this feel a little "brute force" to you at all?  E.g., could we have defined an `OperationType` to be the union type of the string operations and used that somehow?  Or does getting too fancy make it unreadable?

Comment: @icfantv the only simplification that is possible i think is the last to cases can be merged: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAygxgCwgWwIZQLwCgpQD5QDeUARAPZgkBcpwEAzsCQDSlirALVSMBOAlgDsA5qxIA3VABsArhG58hwqAF8c+IqQrcSvFGXHyx7TguACRq9QWLlKNEqgAmTlmw5caikWMmz5XuZKANoAuqpQAPSRUH5yUHCoglAARtDB3qI8QSKh1pp2OnpgUqhwRu6mgRZZEtJy3AAsAExWuDZa9qTIBvIaJHAUIG4kAGa8ZMhmNcYe00ptUFhYUhDAUGQ08EhomJoUDj2GbuOTDm4mCOdWq+tkzVuIKOgY+2AOekcVp8jnrJfnFRRGIQXi8IA

Comment: @icfantv just notices `test` also has the same members with the same types so taht can be added into the last case as well .. but I think that should be it ..

Comment: Yea, ok.  I think maybe I'm just over-thinking it.  Bias towards action.  Moving on.  Thanks all!.

Comment: This is a super cool solution,but TS gives me an error when I want to access `value` within my selector...

Comment: @jake-ferguson ask another question , post your code with the actual error and maybe I can have a look (or someone else surely will :) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663055/typescript-conditional-property-base-on-another-property-with-union-type-gives 

:)