# Typescript - conditional property base on another property with Union type gives an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I prepared an union type like below:

```
export type UnionType =
  | {
      id: 1;
      obj: {
        a: string;
        b: string;
      };
    }
  | {
      id: 2;
      obj: {
        a: string;
      };
    };
```

Unfortunately it breaks within my selector, when I want to access b property like: xxx.b.

```
export const selectB = createSelector(
  [selectObj],
  (someArr: UnionType[]) =>
    (someArr.find(ob => ob.id === 1)
      ?.obj?.b) || '',
);
```

The error is:

> Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'.

Can we somehow work around it?

Comment: Could you post the code with the actual error please

Comment: Explain and add your code regarding: `Unfortunately it breaks within my selector, when I want to access b property like: xxx.b`.  if you set the `id: 2` and add `b` property in your `obj ` then typescript correctly raise an error that `Property 'b' does not exist on type '{ a: string; }'.`

Comment: You have to narrow down the type before you can use `b`. Something like `if(x.id === 1) {/* here you can use x.obj.b */}`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem (at least based on the error) is that if you have a discriminated union, you must perform checks to see in which of the cases you are. You can do this either using a series of `if` statements, or a `switch` on the discriminant field:

```
declare let o: UnionType;

o.obj.b // error
switch(o.id) {
  case 1: o.obj.b; break // ok here
  case 2: o.obj.b; break // not ok on this branch
  default: assertNever(o); // Optional, ensure no casses are missed, o shoudl be never
}

function assertNever(o: never) {
  throw new Error("Not supported")
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCqA7AlhDAVZVAXgCg44AfOAbzPLiwBMAuOARgG47yIAjAK1a169AIasAzjChYMAcy4jyvSdNkLucAL6LtdKsPpNWAJl08BQzeXFwpM+ee26dJEo2ABjADaioqb2B4CFZMHHxCLhIIADo+fhjeOAB6ZLhgKChoEgkAdywYTwALAApYpgBKGjpPUQlUNlZY+MSOOF5-UQBrFLSIHqKM4Bq61BMmuIFW9s6e1LgMCGCe3AQirAkZ0Qxiug8AM1EAV28YVjr62AA5YAA3DLKKtvmAeTAYcNFvABp0jAkjv4FhA4LUJPVNn5UABbDb1Ri-EESIoQI6MbztVAYO4ZEhaNz7I47D6rC4ZGA3e5QMqsbFUqqGGBFLK5BbAVkAUUy0BKACIrks7EcwJBYMBGLyKniSEA)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
obj["b"]
```